# Can you specify empty HTML attributes syntax in MVC helpers?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I'm curious... can you specify an HTML attribute that is empty or valueless?
The W3 spec allows for [empty attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#syntax-attr-empty) like so:
`<input type="checkbox" disabled checked>`

And with MVC, you declare inputs like this:`Html.CheckBoxFor(m=>m.Foo)`.
You can add Html Attributes with the `Html.CheckBoxFor(m=>m.Foo, new {@class="myCssClass"})` syntax, but you can't do `Html.CheckBoxFor(m=>m.Foo, new { disabled, checked})`

I know the spec also allows for self-value attributes for these kinds (e.g. `new {disabled="disabled"}`) and empty string values (e.g. `new {disabled=""}`).

I'm just curious if there is any way to specify the empty syntax.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4135258/asp-net-mvc-htmlattribute-without-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, standard HTML helpers doesn't support this. You could write a custom HTML helper and build the markup yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Late to the party, but ... this from w3schools:

"In XHTML, attribute minimization is forbidden, and the disabled attribute must be defined as: select disabled="disabled".

So for compliance, don't even try to use attribute minimization? But it seems the HTML helpers don't allow it anyway.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_disabled.asp

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. Set it to `string.Empty` and MVC5 will render an empty attribute.

```
new { disabled = string.Empty }
```

And yes, the HTML5 spec ***does allow empty attributes*** perfectly. XHTML is outdated.